# The table row doesn't update after closing modal dialog (Vue3, Composition API, DevExtreme)

Tags: vuejs3, vue-composition-api

I'm in the process of migrating app from Vue2 to Vue3 and have some issues with reactivity. There's a table with rows. The data source of the table is array of objects. When you double click particular row, the modal dialog opens up. You can edit some values and click "Save" to return back and update the table with new data in that row. When I click "Save" and take a look at the array of objects, it is changed, that is new data are there, but the table's row is not updated as was the case in Vue2.

The code looks as following:

**v-reqtype-manager.vue:**

```
<template>
  <div>
    <v-data-table
      :data-source="reqtypes"
      key-expr="fbReqtypeid"
      :columns="columns"
      @row-dbl-click="rowDblClick"
    >
      ...
    </v-data-table>

    <v-app-types-modal ref="appTypesModal" @ok="onOk" />
  </div>
</template>

<script>
...
export default {
  setup() {
    const appTypesModal = ref(null)
    let reqtypes = reactive([
      {
        fbReqtypeid: "1",
        listItem: 'aaaa',
        type: "AAAA",
        link: "https://yandex.ru",
        digits: '1234',
        typeName: "Type A",
        genericName: "Generic A",
        singleLineText: "https://yandex.ru",
        multiLineText:
          "Japan is a sovereign island nation in East Asia. Located in the Pacific Ocean, it lies off the eastern coast of the Asian mainland and stretches from the Sea of Okhotsk in the north to the East China Sea and China in the southwest.",
      },
      {
        fbReqtypeid: "2",
        listItem: 'bbbb',
        type: "BBBB",
        link: "https://stackoverflow.com",
        digits: '5678',
        typeName: "Type B",
        genericName: "Generic B",
        singleLineText:
          "Japan is a sovereign island nation in East Asia.",
        multiLineText:
          "Japan is a sovereign island nation in East Asia. Located in the Pacific Ocean, it lies off the eastern coast of the Asian mainland and stretches from the Sea of Okhotsk in the north to the East China Sea and China in the southwest. The Greater Tokyo Area is the most populous metropolitan area in the world.",
      },
    ])
    const columns = reactive([
      { dataField: "fbReqtypeid", caption: "ID", dataType: "string", visible: false },
      { dataField: "listItem", caption: "List item", dataType: "string" },
      { dataField: "type", caption: "Request type", dataType: "string", cellTemplate: "link-to-modal" },
      { dataField: "link", caption: "Link", dataType: "string" },
      { dataField: "digits", caption: "Digits", dataType: "string" },
      { dataField: "typeName", caption: "Request type name", dataType: "string" },
      { dataField: "genericName", caption: "Generic name", dataType: "string" },
      { dataField: "singleLineText", caption: "Single line", dataType: "string" },
      { dataField: "multiLineText", caption: "Multi line", dataType: "string" },
    ])

    function rowDblClick(e) {
      showModal(e.data);
    }

    function showModal(selectedReqtype) {
      appTypesModal.value.showModal(selectedReqtype);
    }

    function onOk(obj) {
      const indexToUpdate = reqtypes.findIndex(item => item.fbReqtypeid === obj.fbReqtypeid);
      reqtypes.splice(indexToUpdate, 1, obj);
    }

    return {
      reqtypes,
      columns,
      rowDblClick,
      showModal,
      onOk,
      appTypesModal
    }
  }
}
</script>
```

**v-data-table.vue:**

```
<template>
  <DxDataGrid
    v-bind="$attrs"
    :auto-navigate-to-focused-row="true"
    :focused-row-enabled="true"
    :hover-state-enabled="true"
    :show-borders="false"
    :show-column-lines="true"
  >
    <template v-for="(_, slot) in $slots" #[slot]="props">
      <slot :name="slot" v-bind="props || {}" />
    </template>

    <slot name="tools" />

    <DxLoadPanel :enabled="true" />
    <DxFilterRow :visible="isFilterRowEnabled" />
    <DxSelection mode="single" />
    <DxScrolling v-if="isVirtualScrollingEnabled" mode="virtual" />
    <DxPaging v-else :page-size="pageSize" :enabled="isPageSizeEnabled" />
    <DxPager />
  </DxDataGrid>
</template>

<script>
import {
  DxDataGrid,
  DxScrolling,
  DxSelection,
  DxPaging,
  DxFilterRow,
  DxPager,
  DxLoadPanel,
} from "devextreme-vue/data-grid";

export default {
  inheritAttrs: false,
  components: {
    DxDataGrid,
    DxScrolling,
    DxSelection,
    DxFilterRow,
    DxPaging,
    DxPager,
    DxLoadPanel,
  },
  props: {
    pageSize: {
      type: Number,
      default: 2,
    },
    isPageSizeEnabled: {
      type: Boolean,
      default: false,
    },
    isFilterRowEnabled: {
      type: Boolean,
      default: false,
    },
    isVirtualScrollingEnabled: {
      type: Boolean,
      default: true,
    },
  },
  setup() {
    return {
    }
  }
};
</script>

<style scoped>
.add-button {
  border: 0px;
}
:deep(.dx-button-content) {
  padding: inherit;
}
:deep(.dx-icon) {
  border: 1px solid #8ca8cc;
  border-radius: 16px;
  padding: 4px;
}
:deep(.dx-datagrid-text-content) {
  color: #0d356c;
  font-size: 14px;
  font-weight: 700;
  font-family: HelveticaNeueCyr, Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;
}
.loading-indicator {
  text-align: center;
  padding-top: 110px;
}
</style>
```

I'm not sure what I'm doing wrong.

**UPDATE**

CodeSandbox:

https://codesandbox.io/s/overview-devextreme-data-grid-forked-qck9mf

Comment: Seems all right. Is the list reactive in the given component (i.e. if you add a simple display)? What happens in `v-data-table`? If you could provide a sandbox, it would makes things easier

Comment: What happens if you, instead of splice, do: `reqtypes[indexToUpdate] = obj;`

Comment: @Moritz: **v-data-table.vue** is in the original post now.

Comment: @Gabe: It doesn't help.

Comment: Have you tried making `dataSource` a real prop instead of using `$attrs`?

Comment: Please, take a look at UPDATE section in the original post. There is CodeSandbox link.

Comment: Seems like the DxDataGrid component only notices changes in actual values, but not when you update an array item. What works is setting the actual values in the `onOK` function, like `reqtypes[indexToUpdate].type = obj.type`. Looks like a bug in the DxDataGrid component?

Comment: Please, take a look at the SOLUTION section in the original post.

Comment: Posting the answer inside the question severely diminishes the question's ability to help other users with a similar problem. Please post the answer as an answer and mark it as accepted, as it will change the way the question is indexed by search engines and by [SO].

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**SOLUTION**

**v-reqtype-manager:**

```
<template>
  <div>
    <v-data-table
      :dataSource="reqtypes"
      key-expr="fbReqtypeid"
      :columns="columns"
      :isFilterRowEnabled="false"
      :isLoading="isLoading"
      @row-dbl-click="rowDblClick"
      @initialized="saveGridInstance"
    >
      ...

<script>
...
export default {
  ...
  setup() {
    ...
    let dataGridInstance = null

    const saveGridInstance = (e) => {
      dataGridInstance = e.component;
    }

    function onOk(obj) {
        const indexToUpdate = reqtypes.findIndex(item => item.fbReqtypeid === obj.fbReqtypeid);
        reqtypes.splice(indexToUpdate, 1, obj);
        dataGridInstance.refresh(true);
    }
    ...
}
```